# create all possible pairs from column grouped by other columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe, like the input data example below.  I would like to create a new dataframe that has every possible pair of productnames, with the same tz_brandname and producttype.  I have example desired output below.  Is there a quicker way to do this than a self join on tz_brandname and producttype?

input:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+
|tz_brandname|producttype|productname|
+------------+-----------+-----------+
|brand1      |toy        |green duck |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
|brand1      |toy        |toy sky win|
+------------+-----------+-----------+
|brand1      |toy        |duck black |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
|brand2      |game       |sky flyer  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

desired output:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|tz_brandname|producttype|productname|productname|
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|brand1      |toy        |green duck |toy sky win|
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|brand1      |toy        |green duck |duck black |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|brand1      |toy        |toy sky win|green duck |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|brand1      |toy        |toy sky win|duck black |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|brand1      |toy        |duck black |green duck |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|brand1      |toy        |duck black |toy sky win|
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: I can't imagine any method beating a self join for this purpose, since the self join wouldn't do any extra work assuming you filter on the product name being different in the join.

Comment: Did you encounter any performance issues with a join ?

Answer (score 0):

"has every possible pair of productnames" sounds like a cartesian product.
This is also known as an unrestricted join (so it's in the name).

You need to do a join and assuming you want only `producttype` = `toy`:

```scala
val onlyToys = 
 input
   .filter(col("producttype") === "toy")

val productNames = 
 onlyToys
   .select("productname")
   .distinct()

//explicit cartesian join with `productNames`
val output = 
  onlyToys
    .crossJoin(productNames)
```